# How Moxy and Jackson map Json to Pojo

Tags: java, jackson, moxy

### Json to pojo using Jackson

*We can convert Json to Pojo using jackson,i hope that includes Serialization and deserialization of json, But my question is how it's map every attribute of json to pojo. Basically internally how jacskon works?
Sample code to convert json to pojo*

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'Eng'}";
User user = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, User.class);

  class User{
     public String name;
     // getter and setter for name  
    }
```

### json to pojo using Moxy

*Similar way by adding few configuration we can map json to Pojo using moxy.How its works internally taking above example?
 - Which approach is effective and why?*

Comment: Jackson is an open source library. You're welcome to dig in the code and find by yourself

Comment: @SharonBenAsher thanks but how moxy works and i m not able to find out code for jackson library

Comment: try google "code for jackson library". take first result

Comment: https://github.com/jondot/moxy